# form post is omitted after jquery validation is completed

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

### **UPDATE:** Closing this thread since issue was the remote post was interfering with form post. More can be found at this [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985821/jquery-validator-form-how-to-access-form-action-after-the-completion-of-a-remo)

Before I add validation, the form is posting correctly.

Got this form, which validates the email and after it is done the form completes the `onsubmit` javascript function but the data of the form is not posted? Why?

Also I tried to use the action but after the form is validated the action is never used.

Here is the form:

```
<form  id="signup_form" name="signup_form"  method="post" onsubmit="loadPage('registration')">  
<!--action="/registration" method="post"--> 
  <h2>E-MAIL ADDRESS<sup><b>*</b></sup></h2>
  <input value="<?=$uEmail?>" type="text" name="signup_email" id="signup_email" size="40" class="" style="margin-right:6px;font-size:18px" /><br /><label for="signup_email">Example: me@mydomain.com</label>
  <br class="clear" /><br />
  <h2>PASSWORD<sup><b>*</b></sup></h2>
  <input type="password" name="requiredpWord" id="requiredpWord"  size="15" style="width:120px" ><br />
  <h2>CONFIRM PASSWORD<sup><b>*</b></sup></h2>
  <input type="password" name="requiredcpWord" id="requiredcpWord"  size="15" style="width:120px" ><br />
  <button id="submitBTN" type="submit" value="COMPLETE SIGNUP">COMPLETE SIGN UP</button>
</form>
```

The action is commented out and I tried using that to replace the onsubit but when I do the action of pressing the button does nothing.

Here is the form JQuery validation, which works. I added the submitHandler to see if the form would include the post. it did nothing as of now.

```
$(function() {
    $("#signup_form").validate({
        rules: {
            signup_email: {
                email: true,
                required: true,
                remote: { 
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'registration/isEmailAvailable',
                    data: {
                        email:
                            function() {
                                 // console.log(data);
                                return $( "#signup_email" ).val();
                            }
                    }
                }
            },
            requiredpWord: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            requiredcpWord: {
                equalTo: "#requiredpWord"
            }
        },
       messages: {
          signup_email: {
            required: "Please provide an email",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"//,
           },
          requiredpWord: {
            required: "Please provide a password.",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 8 characters long"
           },
          requiredcpWord: "Your passwords do not match."
      },
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
       var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
       if (errors) {
          var message = errors == 1
          ? 'Please correct the following error:\n'
          : 'Please correct the following ' + errors + ' errors.\n';
          var errors = "";
          if (validator.errorList.length > 0) {
           for (x=0;x<validator.errorList.length;x++) {
               errors += "\n\u25CF " + validator.errorList[x].message;
           }
        }
       alert(message + errors);
      }
      validator.focusInvalid();
     },
      //added this to see if the form would post, did not change it
       submitHandler: 
         function(form) {
              // do other things for a valid form
              form.submit();
           }
});
```

the php code is simple...

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
```

The **POST** returns an empty array. No form data at all.

The **GET** returns **"registration"**

The `loadPage("registration")` function is simply the following:

```
function loadPage(name){    
    window.location.replace('/'+name);

}
```

So to reiterate my questions:

1. Why is the form data missing from the POST?
2. **BONUS:** Why after the form validates the action does nothing, but onsubmit works? Note this holds true if I exclude the `submitHandler` from the JQuery validation.

**Update:** Test for Form validation, form is validating as true or false correctly.

```
$( "#submitBTN" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Valid: " + $("#signup_form").valid() );
});
```

**UPDATE:**

1. Added invalidHandler code, form validates correctly, displays only if there is an error. This is not a validation issue.
2. Removed onsubmit for action, now validation does nothing. Using jQuery validation plug-in 1.7. I'm going to check for a newer release. **NOTE** code above  still displays onsubmit because i don't want to change the whole problem.
3. submitHandler is also uncommented. The alert is not being displayed.

**UPDATE 4**
Issue resides with remote post for email validation. If i comment out the remote verification the post actually completes. Opened a new question based upon this finding.

Comment: Do you have an error in the console debug in the browser?

Comment: @bicho No I do not, I am a fan of console. It was suggested the onSubmit was redirecting the page via javascript before creating the POST. Could this be true?

Comment: DId you try without submit, just with jQuery and Ajax?

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

Comment: @Hackermanc your reply is useless!! The form validation works.

Comment: I added the test to check if the form is valid and Yes it is.

Comment: @bicho yes I did as suggested. I tried to let the submitHandler process the request it doesn't seem to ever make it there. Even though the form was validating as true. note I commented that out because I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `onsubmit="loadPage('registration')"` and uncommenting the `submitHandler` part should do the job.
Also uncomment the `action="/registration"` in the form's attribute list

Comment: This behaves the same as when the submit button is pressed and action="/registration". It does nothing.

Comment: what happens if you put an `alert` as the first line inside `submitHandler` function?

Comment: Nothing! I'm looking at the html in firebug and a error message is still there but have style of `action="/registration"` I reloaded the form and redid it, still the same and no error messages are present.  Realized I must of pressed the submit button first.

Comment: can you show the error message you got in the console?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't get one. If I use onsubmit as i detailed in my question I reach my destination but there is no post. I also have an alert saying my form is valid = true.

Comment: My console does display that the post I did for the remote validation to verify the email address entered is not already registered is working.

Comment: First thing, the `onsubmit` won't work, because `loadPage` function is only redirecting you to the `/registration` page without submitting the form. remove all these extra code lines. Also try to once add `invalidHandler` also and put an `alert` in this, just in case your code is getting stuck there.

Comment: Please refer to my new update, just a quick recap the invalidHandler just reports the issues of an invalid form correctly. I added the code. I switched the action and onsubmit and now the page goes no where. I am looking into my plug-in maybe it is outdated.