# jquery validator form: how to access form action, after the completion of a remote email validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

**History:** I started this issue off previously in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966294/form-post-is-omitted-after-jquery-validation-is-completed). I spent sometime trying to get the remote validation working so I refused to believe that was what was causing me grief.

**Present:** I am using jQuery Validator and I have updated the js to version 1.14.0. This process is working smoothly. All fields are being checked and validated, I even added few extra checks to help me identify issues:

`invalidHandler` and `$("#submitBTN").click()`, detailed below.

Both of these options would report back if the validation failed, and the button also reported passed validations by calling `$(form).valid();`

I have a remote validation which is verifying the email address, checking to see if it is already in the database. It is working. I submit this request using a post. Should I be using an alternate technique? I say this because the post of the form upon validation is not being submitted.

I do not even make it inside of `submitHandler` but if I comment out the remote check I am able to access `submitHandler` and the form action is processed.

I have reviewed [jQuery Validation Remote](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) rules but it is very simply laid out so what have I done incorrectly?

Here is my html form code:

```
<form  id="signup_form" name="signup_form"  method="post" action="registration">  
  <h2>E-MAIL ADDRESS</h2>
  <input value="<?=$uEmail?>" type="text" name="signup_email" id="signup_email" /><br />

  <h2>PASSWORD</h2>
  <input type="password" name="requiredpWord" id="requiredpWord"><br />

  <h2>CONFIRM PASSWORD</h2>
  <input type="password" name="requiredcpWord" id="requiredcpWord"><br />

  <button id="submitBTN" type="submit" value="COMPLETE SIGNUP">COMPLETE SIGN UP</button>
</form>
```

Here is my jQuery Validation (**Note** I use a mix of  `console.log` & `alert` for debugging):

```
$(function() {
    $("#signup_form").validate({
        rules: {
            signup_email: {
                email: true,
                required: true,
                remote: { 
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'registration/isEmailAvailable',
                    data: {
                        email:
                            function() {
                                 // console.log(data);
                                return $( "#signup_email" ).val();
                            }
                    }
                }
            },
            requiredpWord: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            requiredcpWord: {
                equalTo: "#requiredpWord"
            }
        },
       messages: {
            signup_email: {
                required: "Please provide an email",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"//,
            },
            requiredpWord: {
                required: "Please provide a password.",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 8 characters long"
            },
            requiredcpWord: "Your passwords do not match."
        },
        invalidHandler: 
            function(form, validator) {
                var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                if (errors) {
                    var message = errors == 1
                    ? 'Please correct the following error:\n'
                    : 'Please correct the following ' + errors + ' errors.\n';
                    var errors = "";
                    if (validator.errorList.length > 0) {
                        for (x=0;x<validator.errorList.length;x++) {
                            errors += "\n\u25CF " + validator.errorList[x].message;
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(message + errors);
                }
                validator.focusInvalid();
            },
        //added this to see if the form would post, did not change it
        submitHandler: 
            function(form) {
                alert("form submitted");
                // do other things for a valid form
                form.submit();
            }
    });
})
```

Here is my button js validation:

```
$( "#submitBTN" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Valid: " + $("#signup_form").valid() );
});
```

Here is my simple php validation script that the after the form is validated I can read it:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

**Validation with Remote Section Enabled:**

When I press submit the alert reports:

`Valid: true`.

The console reports the validation post of the email address. Nothing else occurs, or is reported. The page remains on the form.

**Validation with Remote Section Disabled/Commented Out:**

If I comment out the remote validation section completely:

I view the following alerts:

`Valid: true` && `form submitted`

Followed by the var_dump of the $_POST. Which displays that the form action has been completed.

Any suggestions on how I can get this to work would be greatly appreciated?!

**UPDATE**

the remote check pretty much returns the following:

```
if(!$userHandler->isEmailAvailable($email)){
    echo json_encode("Email Address is already registered: ".$email);
}else{
    echo false;
}
exit;
```

If a true is returned the result becomes the error message, 1.

Comment: Firstly, you don't need a `click` handler on the `button`.  The button is already a `type="submit"` so the plugin will capture it automatically.  Remove your entire `click` handler and see what happens.  Secondly, since this is apparently an issue with `remote`, then show us your server side script too.

Comment: I just added that for extra validation. It actually doesn't do anything more. So your advice is not helpful! :(

Comment: What is *"extra validation"* supposed to mean?  And yes, it does... it captures the click while the plugin is also trying to capture the same click.  You do not need two `click` handlers.  BTW, [I know a little about this plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/topusers).  Despite that, maybe tone down the attitude towards people trying to help you.  Meanwhile, the second part of my comment is asking you to show us the server-side script.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sparky Apologies if I came off as being offensive. I actually have the remote commented out so I can move forward at the moment.  I can't post all the server side code but I can do the final results if it finds another user or if it doesn't. And I appreciate all help it just seems I'm running in circles at times. This is the my first implementation of jQuery Validator.

Comment: Simply post the ***relevant*** server-side code, showing how the response(s) are generated.  Also, you *should* see the `submitHandler` fire on a valid form and the `invalidHandler` fire on an invalid form... there is no third condition where neither one fires.  Remove your `click` handler and try it.

Comment: extra validation, the submit button was also testing to see if the form is valid. it is detailed in the code above. I also used invalidHandler as another means of verification. both work like a charm. i actually placed these things in because others suggested it from my initial thread. if you read my whole message you will see that if I don't have the remote option included the form will submit. also if I include the remote, that check is done and it reports back correctly but the form submit will not work. maybe I am returning a bad value from the remote check. :)

Comment: *"maybe I am returning a bad value from the remote check."* ~ Again, post the *relevant* server-side code, showing how the response(s) are generated.

Comment: *"others suggested it from my initial thread"* ~ maybe so, however in general, the misuse and misunderstanding about how this plugin works is widespread.

Comment: I posted the snippet of what my server side code returns above. I hope that helps. I think it was a string before not sure why I surrounded it with a json_encode. Might not need that.

Comment: The `json_encode` is correct.  However, the `false` and the message mean the same.... failed validation so the conditional makes no sense.  You'll want to `echo "true"` to represent a "valid" condition.  Note the quotation marks around the `true`.

Comment: @Sparky you're a genius!!!! WOO HOO!!! Wish that was explained more clearly inthe remote section of jQuery Validation. I returned a true as suggested and I got an error message of 1.

Comment: I submitted a pull request several months ago that clarified the `remote` documentation.  I don't think it's gone live yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server-side code should look more like this...

```
if (!$userHandler->isEmailAvailable($email)) {
    // failed validation
    echo json_encode("Email Address is already registered: " . $email); 
} else {
    // passed validation
    echo "true"; 
}
exit;
```

> If a `true` is returned the result becomes the error message, `1`.

That is because the `true` is a boolean (`1`), and the plugin is expecting a string.  Literally, *anything* that is not a `"true"` (string), is considered failed validation and will give you an error message:

- If the response is `"false"`, `undefined`, or `null`, then you get the generic error message.
- If the response is `"true"`, then you've passed validation and no message is displayed.
- If the response is anything else, that response becomes the error message string.

Comment: Is the above statement true for all java script? or just jQuery Validator?

Comment: @mcv, which statement exactly?

Comment: That return is true is evaluated as a 1, So "true" must be sent by a string?
See I read that a true should be returned but not in quotes in [jQuery remote validator](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) I guess that's why I returned a false, because true resulted in a 1.

Comment: @mvc, a boolean `true` is the same as a `1`.  A `"true"` with quotes is just a string.  This has nothing to do with any particular programming language.  It has everything to do with how the plugin was designed to handle the response from the server.  It's simply looking for a string... so `true` is a `"1"`, and `"true"` is `"true"`.  I reworded my answer a little.

Comment: Your explanation is much clearer than the jQuery validator site in the remote section. It just states true. I took that to mean without " ". So when I got an error message of 1, I thought huh... and read it as an empty string must be the answer it is looking for. Maybe they could fix the plugin so that the response of 1 is also valid. :)

Comment: @mcv, the documentation needs to be generic since the server-side code is not necessarily a PHP `echo` ... it could be a Perl `print`, etc.  However, I already fixed the documentation regarding the quotation marks in the responses and it just needs to be posted online.